# How to make bellman-ford run in worst case?

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

I am trying to make optimized version of bellman ford algorithm to run in worst case. Optimized version I mean if after relaxing 1 round of edges and there is no further update on the shortest distance, it terminates.

For instance, a simple connected weighted directed graph with 7 vertices such that running Optimized Bellman-Ford's algorithm from source vertex 0 uses at least 5 rounds to get the correct shortest paths.

The graph cannot contain a negative weight cycle.
i.e. all outgoing edges from vertex 0 is processed then edges from vertex 1 and so on

I know it has to do with cycles. But i am not very sure the strategy in drawing the graph to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the Bellman-Ford algorithm will need as many iterations as the longest length (in edges) of all shortest paths in the graph.

Consider a directed graph with *n* vertices. You add edges *1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... -> n* to the graph, each having a small positive weight. Then you can add as many arbitrary *heavy* edges as you want. It is clear that the shortest path from *1* to *n* has length *n-1*. Thus your algorithm will need exactly *n-1* iterations.

On further note, there is an improved version of the Bellman-Ford algorithm. It is called the [Shortest Path Faster Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_Path_Faster_Algorithm). Although it has a worst-case run-time of `O(|V|*|E|)`, which is the same as Bellman-Ford, very few graphs can make the algorithm reach that time. In practice, you can expect an average runtime of `O(|E|)` (unproven).